# Variable not expanding when invoking curl command with gitlab ci

Tags: bash, shell, curl, gitlab

I am invoking the following curl command from a gitlab ci yml file.
The variable jrun is not getting expanded.

```
'curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/454939/variables/$jrun" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"'
```

`echo "$jrun"`  prints the value correctly `run1234`.

Would appreciate any help in this regard. Have searched through the forum and tried different options.

Tried various options:

```
'curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/454939/variables/"$jrun" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"'
'curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/454939/variables/$jrun" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"'
```

Defined the command as a variable Jcommand:

```
'curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/454939/variables/$jrun" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"'
```

And tried `'eval "$Jcommand"'`.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: can you please attach curl logs? this command works fine: `curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/454939/variables/$jrun" -H "Authorization:Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"`

Comment: Do you also use the outermost single quotes in your yml file ? Have you tried without them ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your responses and comments.

@nquincampoix - this curl command is within a gitlab-ci yml file. So it had to start with single quotes.

So this is what worked at the end.
Passing a fully expanded url to the curl command. I used the following to expand the url.

- url="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/45482939/variables/${jrun}"
- xUrl = $url
- 'curl "$xUrl" -H "Authorization: Bearer $GIT_SERVICE_TOKEN"'